# Can embedded methods access "parent" fields?

Tags: go

**Background**

I've done a fair amount of spec reading and code testing and I think the answer is no, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

**Goal**

Basically, I'm trying to create a Active Record style ORM for Go, because I like how readable it is and how abstracted it is from its back end data store. I'd rather write `user.Save()` than `data.Save(user)` by embedding common CRUD methods on the user struct.

**Example**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    test := Foo{Bar: &Bar{}, Name: "name"}
    test.Test()
}

type Foo struct {
    *Bar
    Name string
}

func (s *Foo) Method() {
    fmt.Println("Foo.Method()")
}

type Bar struct {
}

func (s *Bar) Test() {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
    fmt.Printf("model: %+v %+v %+v\n", s, t, v)
    fmt.Println(s.Name)
    s.Method()
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/cWyqqVSKGH

**Question**

Is there a way to make top-level fields (not sure what the correct term in Go is for these) accessible from embedded methods (eg: `s.Name` or `s.Method()`?

Thank you donating your time to a new Gopher.

Comment: See solution for similar question on this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153269/how-to-reflect-fields-of-containing-struct-from-a-method-of-the-embedded-struct?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go doesn't provide any support for what you're after: the receiver of your `Test` method is a `Bar` pointer, and there is no way to tell whether it is embedded or not.

If you really want to go this route, one option would be to add an `interface{}` member to `Bar` and require that types that it be set to the containing type.  Initialising this member could either be the responsibility of whoever created the value, or perhaps require callers to pass the value to some ORM method to set it.  This isn't particularly pretty, but it's probably the best you can do.

With that out of the way, is it really that bad to structure the API as `db.Save(user)` rather than `user.Save()`?  The former offers an obvious way to extend to multiple databases, while the latter seems more likely to rely on global state.

Comment: This is exactly the route I took. I won't answer my on question since you posted yours first, but I will provide my solution to compliment your answer: http://play.golang.org/p/v7lC0swB3s . As far as why I would want to avoid `db.Save(&user)`, it requires more specifics to be managed by the application. My idea for an ORM allows you to set an active db driver and then forget about it so that you can focus on your model CRUD in the most terse way possible. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Brenden did you ever implement this reflection approach? Did you find it performed well enough and you were happy with the overhead and "magic"?

Answer (score 0):

(If I understood your question correctly,) no, embedding isn't inheritance. It sounds like what you're actually after is an interface

```
type Saver interface {
    Save() error
}
```

then the relevant parties can implement that.

You can have a common struct `base` or whatever that implements common methods and then each higher-level struct can embed `base` to allow them to share implementation.

Comment: I want to avoid having a custom implementation for every struct that implements the interface.