# Golang struct composition - composed with struct cannot access its "parent"

Tags: go, struct, composition

This question appears to be a duplicate of [Can embedded methods access "parent" fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167935/can-embedded-methods-access-parent-fields), but it is not in the sense that I know that there is no way to access the "parent" fields; I am just looking for suggestions on another way to do this, because I like the idea of the `Pausable` struct.

---

I am trying to make a convenience struct that enables other structs to receive some pausing/unpausing methods.

Imagine the following:

**Pausable struct**

```
type Pausable struct {
    isPaused bool
}

func (p *Pausable) Pause() {
    p.isPaused = true
}

func (p *Pausable) Unpause() {
    p.isPaused = false
}
```

**Struct that composes with Pausable**

Now on my other struct I want to overwrite the `Unpause()` method, so that besides changing the value of `p.isPaused` some other stuff happens as well.

```
type Mystruct struct {
    Pausable // Composition
}

func (s *Mystruct) Unpause() {
    s.Unpause()

    // Do other stuff
}
```

**Problem**

The problem becomes this. I want to add an `PauseUntil()` method to the `Pausable` struct, so that it becomes

```
type Pausable struct {
    isPaused bool
}

func (p *Pausable) Pause() {
    p.isPaused = true
}

func (p *Pausable) Unpause() {
    p.isPaused = false
}

func (p *Pausable) PauseUntil(dur time.Duration) {
    p.Pause()

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(dur)
        p.Unpause()
    }()
}
```

When the timeout runs out, however, `Unpause()` is called on `Pausable`, and not on `Mystruct`. What would be a clever way around this?

Comment: Implementing `PauseUntil` on your `Mystruct` type, otherwise no it won't be able to access the fields/methods of a structure that is composed of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can embedded methods access "parent" fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167935/can-embedded-methods-access-parent-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `PauseUntil` a function that operates on a `Pauser` interface.

E.g.

```
type Pauser interface {
    Pause()
    Unpause()
}

func PauseUntil(p Pauser) {
    p.Pause()

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(dur)
        p.Unpause()
    }()
}
```

Then you should be able to pass your `myStruct` to that function:

```
ms := new(myStruct)
PauseUntil(ms)
```

Comment: I like your solution, although I don't like that I'll end up with a function that is not part of any struct/interface. Only alternative I can think of is giving the `PauseUntil` method a `Pauser` receiver, but then a call like `pauser.PauseUntil(pauser, dur)` would be weird (the pauser calling `PauseUntil` on itself, passing itself as first argument)..