# How to get a pointer of interface{} to type check interface implementation

Tags: pointers, go, interface

So I'm basically trying to find out the best way to get to something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type SomeStruct struct {
}

type SomeInterface interface {
  SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver() string
}

func (s *SomeStruct) SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver() string {
  return "Well, believe me, I wrote something"
}

func Run(s interface{}) {
  // how can I cast s to a pointer here?
  casted, ok := (s).(SomeInterface)
  if ok {
    fmt.Println("Awesome: " + casted.SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver())
    return 
  }

  fmt.Println("Fail :(")
}

func SomeThirdPartyMethod() interface{} {
  return SomeStruct{}
}

func main() {
  x := SomeThirdPartyMethod()
  Run(x)
}
```

My problem here is, at the typecast in the Run method.
I basically only know that it is of type interface{} and now I need
to call an interface method, which has a pointer receiver.

My only solution at the moment is to dynamically construct a slice with reflection, set the element into the slice, and than make it adressable.

Is this really the only possibility to find a solution?

[Play link](https://play.golang.org/p/4JCSmZkIxv)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically call method on interface{} regardless of receiver type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116840/dynamically-call-method-on-interface-regardless-of-receiver-type)

Comment: well not really, since I actually want a solution without reflection. But yeah, if it isn't possible, it might be a duplicate.

Comment: For me, I don't like third_party_libs which have funcs returning interface{}. To my mind it's untyped, hard to understand and use, bad practice. I'd just avoid to use such a lib. I much prefer SomeThirdPartyMethod() which returns something explicitly - say SomeStruct, or SomeInterface, but not interface{}

Comment: it would be the same if the return type would be of an interface lets say... InterfaceA und it optionally may implemented interfaceB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution would indeed be to return a pointer from `SomeThirdPartyMethod`. But if this is not possible, you can construct a pointer to that value using [reflection](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/):

```
v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(s)))
v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(s))
sp := v.Addr().Interface()
casted, ok = (sp).(SomeInterface)
if ok {
    fmt.Println("Good as well: " + casted.SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver())
    return
}
```

Working example: http://play.golang.org/p/JYJT8mRxWN

Comment: Yeah that is the only way we found as well. I upvoted you're answer but I will let this question open for now to find other suggestions. But thx for your response for now :D

Answer (score 6):

In Go, an interface is just a set of methods ([spec: Interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)).

The interface does not specify whether receivers are pointers or not. Implementing an interface in Go is implicit: there is no declaration of intent.

You need to read and understand [**Method sets**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets). Quoting an important part of it:

> The method set of any other type `T` consists of all [methods](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) declared with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).

A *value* (which may or may not be a pointer) implements an interface if the method set of its type is a superset of the interface (the methods of the interface type).

In your example:

```
func (s *SomeStruct) SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver() string{}
```

`SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver()` has a pointer receiver, so a value of type `SomeStruct` will not have this method, but a value of type `*SomeStruct` will.

So as a consequence a value of type `SomeStruct` **does not** implement your `SomeInterface` interface (because it does not have a `SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver()` method), but `*SomeStruct` **does implement** your `SomeInterface` because its method set contains the `SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver()` method.

Since you create and use a simple `SomeStruct` value (and not a pointer to it), the type assertion will fail.

Should you have used a `*SomeStruct`, the type assertion would have succeeded.

Modify your `SomeThirdPartyMethod()` function to create and return a `*SomeStruct` (a pointer) and it will work as you expect it:

```
func SomeThirdPartyMethod() interface{} {
    return &SomeStruct{}
}
```

Or as an alternative:

```
func SomeThirdPartyMethod() interface{} {
    return new(SomeStruct)
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/BC1zbqoryc).

#### If you can't modify `SomeThirdPartyMethod()`

If you can't modify the `SomeThirdPartyMethod()` function: first of all, is it intended/required that it returns a value which implements `SomeStruct`? If so, then its current implementation is wrong, and you can expect it to return a value which does implement `SomeStruct` without you having to dereference it (in order to gain a value which implements `SomeStruct`).

In this specific case you can also try type assertion for `SomeStruct` itself:

```
if ss, ok := s.(SomeStruct); ok {
    fmt.Println(ss.SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver())
}
```

Calling `ss.SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver()` will automatically dereference `ss` to take its address (which will be the pointer receiver value for calling the `SomeMethodWhichNeedsAPointerReceiver()` method).

Comment: well, the third party method specifies the interface as optional. So therefore it must not be implemented, and the return value is interface{}. It's not elegant, but that's how it is.