# Reflection - method call panics with "call of reflect.Value.Elem on struct Value"

Tags: go, go-reflect

Here is a code snippet -

```
type Gateway struct {
    Svc1 svc1.Interface
    Svc2 svc2.Interface
}

func (g *Gateway) GetClient(service string) interface{} {
    ps := reflect.ValueOf(g)
    s := ps.Elem()
    f := s.FieldByName(strings.Title(service))
    return f.Interface()
}

func (g *Gateway) Invoke(service string, endpoint string, args... 
    interface{}) []reflect.Value {
    log.Info("Gateway.Invoke " + service + "." + endpoint)
    inputs := make([]reflect.Value, len(args))
    for i, _ := range args {
        inputs[i] = reflect.ValueOf(args[i])
    }

    client := g.GetClient(service)

    return reflect.ValueOf(client).Elem().MethodByName(endpoint).Call(inputs)
}
```

GetClient("svc1") works fine.

However, when I call Invoke("svc1", "endpoint1", someArg), it panics saying -

```
reflect: call of reflect.Value.Elem on struct Value
```

reflect.ValueOf(client).MethodByName(endpoint).Call(inputs) panics saying Call on a zero value.

Comment: I tried the solution for this -
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116840/dynamically-call-method-on-interface-regardless-of-receiver-type?rq=1 and I am calling Invoke("svc1", "Endpoint1", someArgs). Now it does not crash, but can't find the Endpoint1 method as well. How ever if I do a type assertion on GetClient's result and call Endpoint1, that works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically call method on interface{} regardless of receiver type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116840/dynamically-call-method-on-interface-regardless-of-receiver-type)

Answer (score 12):

There are a couple issues:

1. If `svc1.Interface` is not a pointer or an interface, `reflect.Value.Elem()` will panic (see https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem)
2. If the `endpoint` argument string of `Invoke` doesn't match the capitalization of the target method, it will panic due to zero value (`invalid reflect.Value`). Please note that the method you want to call must be exported.

Comment: Yes realized that after looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116840/dynamically-call-method-on-interface-regardless-of-receiver-type?rq=1 Trying to find a way to mark my question as duplicate of that one without down-voting myself :D

Comment: In my in case the interface was not a pointer. Changing it to pointer resolved it.